# Emacs Golang gofmt on save hook - not formatting

Tags: go, emacs, gofmt

after checking path with M-: (eval "**PATH**") the location of *C:/Go/bin* shows up, so I know the [gofmt](/questions/tagged/gofmt) binary is found. If i try to do M-x gofmt on other files it will give proper errors (not *.go files).

however I noticed something weird in the *Messages* which is where the gofmt is trying to format..

> Calling gofmt: gofmt (-w c:/Users/LunchBox/AppData/Local/Temp/gofmt5200q9o.go)
>   Error: (file-error "Searching for program" "no such file or directory" "diff")

why is it looking in the *-w /appdata/locals/temp/etc*..?
shouldn't it be the file I'm working on currently? which is just called ovRESTful.go in c:/work/users/ovRESTful/ovRESTful.go

the line I have for my code..

```
(add-hook 'before-save-hook 'gofmt-before-save)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

diff is the name of a command to compare files line by line which is usually distributed with unix-derived operating systems.

You could try to install these utilities on windows:

http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm

to see if that helps.

Comment: Makes a lot more sense, as they are windows environments and it didn't work on another windows machine.

Comment: worked like a charm! There was nothing on the net that was helping me figure out that issue. +1000 for you!